# When and where did Gauss say this

Tags: ho.history-overview

This quote is often attributed to Gauss: ``Die Mathematik ist die Königin
der Wissenschaften, und die Arithmetik ist die Königin der Mathematik". Where and when did he say that?

Answer (score 8):

According to [Wikiquote](https://de.wikiquote.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gau%C3%9F), this was attributed to Gauss, without specific where and when, by his friend
Wolfgang Sartorius von Waltershausen in his 1856 commemorative tribute "Gauss zum Gedächtniss". As in English, "Kaiserin" (empress) feels a bit more literal than "Königin" (queen), and therefore the latter lends itself better to metaphor.

Comment: A German "Kaiser" had no political powers and duties; his task as a "king of kings" was to defend Christianity and was therefore crowned by the pope, wehereas Kings or Queens were determined by right of birth and they had the final word in political decisions. Even St. Mary is attributed "Himmelskönigin" (queen of heaven) and not "Himmelskaiserin" (empress of heaven.

Comment: @dodd which German queen are you referring to? I guess you mix up things; if the king was still alive it was only because of the classical role of sexes in a relationship that men were expected to be "dominant" if however the king had died, the queen took over leadership. Apart from that the explanation of the difference of "König/Königin" and "Kaiser/Kaiserin" was independent of the underlying sex.

Comment: @dodd - As is known in mathematics, some questions are not as decidable as we may think they are. I explained the intuitive feeling a native German speaker has about the usage of queen/empress in metaphors, and I explained that the quote does not come from an official, documented occasion, but is a quote by a close friend who may have heard Gauss say it on a variety of occasions. I think it's very likely that Gauss actually did say this, because it is reported by an eyewitness with no obvious motive to fabricate.

Comment: @dodd in German language the *grammatical* sex of arithmetic is female *die* Arithmetic, so, provided Gauss actually used an allgoric picture of a "reigning" arithmetic, he had to make it a "queen". And apart from that Germany didn't exist as a political entity at the times of Gauss; he lived in the kingdom of Hannover!

Comment: @dodd - I find your insinuation that a non-mathematician could not be a reliable eyewitness amusing. Wolfgang Sartorius von Waltershausen was a geologist who participated in Gauss' observations of the earth's magnetic field, including in joint travels throughout Europe 1834/35, and they developed a close friendship in old age, evidenced by the fact that  von Waltershausen was chosen by the University of Goettingen to deliver the eulogy at Gauss' funeral.

Comment: @ManfredWeis Although the German empire didn't exist until 1871, there was still a Kaiser: the Holy Roman Emperor until 1806, after that the Austrian (and then Austro-Hungarian) Emperor.  Maria Theresa was a reigning Kaiserin from 1740 to 1780.

Comment: @dodd  - please do strive for accuracy in your factual claims and refrain from using strawmen. I never used the plural "eyewitnesses"; von Waltershausen did not mention the numbers from 1 to 100 (he merely mentions an arithmetic progression); von Waltershausen and Gauss spent about a decade jointly on the faculty of the University of Goettingen, and yes, they spent considerable time together outside of Germany as well, as I mentioned.

Comment: @RobertIsrael it is clear that there are different "flavors" of Kaiser/Kaiserin and I intended to refer to the "traditional" German Kaiser's prior to the foundation of the Kaiserreich, which happened very late in History. Your comment is however a valuable contribution.

Comment: [here](https://beruhmte-zitate.de/zitate/2001606-carl-friedrich-gauss-die-mathematik-ist-die-konigin-der-wissenschaften/?page=2) it is claimed that the original statement was:"*Die Mathematik hielt Gauss um seine eigenen Worte zu gebrauchen, für die Königin der Wissenschaften und die Arithmetik für die Königin der Mathematik.*"

Quelle: https://beruhmte-zitate.de/zitate/2001606-carl-friedrich-gauss-die-mathematik-ist-die-konigin-der-wissenschaften/?page=2

Comment: @ManfredWeis - you can see it in the original by following the books.google.de link on the Wikiquote page I linked to.